# How to add values at repeat index locations on multidimensional arrays of Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix `B` with shape `(6, 9)` . And for every row of `B`, I want to add 1 at some column indices. The column indices may appear more than once, so I hope add m on one column if which index appear m times. Please see the following example codes:

```py
import numpy as np
B = np.arange(6*9).reshape(6, 9)
idx = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                [6, 7, 0], 
                [2, 3, 4],
                [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.int)
B[:, idx] += 1 # the result is not what I want.
```

Furthermore, `np.add.at` and `np.bincount` also do not seem to work for above case.

I hope your help. Thanks very much.

**More Information:**

In `idx` array, index `0`, `2` `4` and `6` appear twice, so I want 
`B[:, [0, 2, 4, 6]] += 2`. For other indices appeared once, just add 1. So the final `B` should be

```py
B = np.array([[ 2,  2,  4,  4,  6,  6,  8,  8,  8],
              [11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17],
              [20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26],
              [29, 29, 31, 31, 33, 33, 35, 35, 35],
              [38, 38, 40, 40, 42, 42, 44, 44, 44],
              [47, 47, 49, 49, 51, 51, 53, 53, 53]])
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: Share how you have used `np.add.at` and `np.bincount`?

Comment: @Divakar, I only known some simple usages of `np.add.at`, so I didn't figure out the solution. Viacheslav Z' answer is exactly the solution what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `np.add.at` function to get what you want. Its syntax is

```
np.add.at('array', ('slice or array of indices for 1st dimension', 'slice or array of indices for 2nd dimension'), 'what to add')
```

So, in your case, if you want to add `1` for every row for every column, specified in `idx`, you should use

```
>>> a = np.arange(6 * 9).reshape(6, 9)
>>> np.add.at(a, (np.s_[:], idx), 1)
```

`np.s_[:]` is a slice object that tells us to *perform it for each row*